Using serverVerifiedData from in_app_purchase flutter package
I'm in_app_purchase package to let users buy a subscription but verifyReceipt endpoint is now deprecated and apple have new server APIs that need transactionId to verify subscription statuses. This package doesn't provide that.
I assumed it might be encoded in serverVerifiedData but it is giving byte extension error when I try to decode it as base64 string

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
